Which meaning should I pick up?
In the sentence below:

This publication is in copyright. Subject to statutory exception
and to the provisions of relevant collective licensing agreements,
no reproduction of any part may take place without the written
permission of Cambridge University Press.

I look up meaning of Subject to in dictionary, find below meaning, but I am not sure which meaning should I pick up, and I don't know what part of speech "subject to" is.

conditionally upon

depending on something in order to be completed or agreed

under the authority of something/someone

in a situation where you have to obey a rule or law

likely to experience something or be affected by something

depending on whether something happens


Who can tell me which meaning should I pick up? Thank you.

"Conditional upon", "under authority", and "in a situation in which you have to obey a law". In particular the demand for "No reproduction" is under the authority of the "statutory exemption", and so conditional on that statute.  The "statute" is the official code of laws.
The copyright holders have to obey the law, so they can't ban all reproduction. They are subject to the law, so the must allow "fair dealing" (such as a short quote in your essay).
The copyright rules are restricted (only) by the law. The copyright holder does not grant any additional exceptions, beyond those required by law, and those already agreed to (licencing agreements).

Thank you for your answer. I can't understand well about "They are subject to the law", shouldn't it be that I am subject to the law?

You both are.  But the important idea here is that the copyright holder demands "No reproduction" But the demand "No reproduction" is subject to the law and cannot legally be 100% enforced.  The copyright holder must allow fair dealing, for example.#

What is meaning of # in for example.#?

A typo. My keyboard has "#" just above the "Enter" key, and my old keyboard had a big "Enter" key that was on two rows.  The effect is that when I touch-type, I often hit "#" instead of "Enter".

I see. Thank you very much.

so the must allow "fair dealing"  -----> so they must allow "fair dealing" , is it right?

The main clause of the second sentence is this:
"...no reproduction of any part [of this publication] may take place without the written permission of Cambridge University Press."
The first clause is a concession that there may be exceptions to that claim, namely "statutory exception" (for example, fair use doctrine), and "provisions of collective licensing agreements" (which they have already agreed to).
The closest answer is your number 1, "conditionally upon".
So, you can't copy it except in the described cases.

Thank you for your answer. But I find your answer is different from @James K's answer. I am not sure whose answer is better.

They are really saying the same thing.  I shall edit mine to make that more clear.

subject to statutory exception could be paraphrased as "Except as permitted by statute".
None of the meanings offered in the question fits perfectly, but I would choose "under the authority of something/someone" since the statute grants permission, under certain exceptional cases, to make reproductions.  The statute is the authority here.

Subject to statutory exception and to the provisions of relevant collective licensing agreements == Subject to statutory exception and subject to the provisions of relevant collective licensing agreements, is it right?

It seems that China does not have a code. China has a constitution, and when you refer to "statute," are you talking about the constitution?

A "statute" is a law.

Yes, you are right, the person is subject to any exceptions in the statute and is subject to the provisions of collective licensing agreements.   So there are statutory freedoms and restrictions, and contractual freedoms and restrictions.

Thank you for your explanation.

Constitutions are also considered integral to the law of a country. They are like the foundation of a house, which is considered part of the house.

According to you said, I think Except as permitted by statute and The statute is the authority here is just suit for subject to statutory exception, and maybe under the authority of something/someone is not very suit for subject to the provisions of relevant collective licensing agreements

@Tom  I don't wish to debate how well a couple of poorly worded definitions fit that sentence, especially since contractual freedoms and restrictions are different from statutory freedoms and restrictions.  However, one is subject to the law and subject to contractual obligations both. The law is the authority that determines whether certain actions are lawful or unlawful. A contract is the authority that determines whether certain actions are permissible. Failing to obey a law has criminal consequences and failing to honor the terms of a contract has civil consequences.

I apologize for my inappropriate behavior. I am not familiar with U.S. law, and I was just trying to understand better and have a discussion. Regarding what you said, "Failing to obey a law has criminal consequences and failing to honor the terms of a contract has civil consequences," I now understand what you meant by "The statute is the authority here." Thank you again for your explanation.

@Tom  Nothing to apologize for.  But a definition in a dictionary is one lexicographer's attempt (or one committee's) to state what a word means.   It should be understood as guidance only, and read in conjunction with other definitions from other dictionaries.   An authority can be an abstraction, not necessarily a person or organization or agency: "that which grants legitimacy; that which grants license";

OK, I see, thank you for your explanation. The explanations in my question are ones I found in several different dictionaries, and the meanings varied, which is why I was a bit confused earlier.
